# How to use LSTM/GRU/RNN for sequence classification with Tensorflow/keras?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow, sequential-analysis

I want to use LSTMs and RNNs for sequence classification problem. I have features extracted from video segment of 10 sec @ 30 fps i.e. total of 300 frames. For each frame I have a feature representation of d-dimensions. I have label associated for for the entire video segment. Thus, my training data looks like [((x_1_1, x_1_2, x_1_3,...,x_1_300), y_1), ((x_2_1, x_2_2, x_2_3,...,x_2_300),y_2),..] and so on. Thus, I have 1 label for sequence of 300 features, each with dimension d. I want to use LSTM/RNNs to learn these representation for sequence classification. Can someone point me in right direction? Most of the code and description on LSTM/RNN in keras I found used (feature, label) rather than (sequence, label).

Comment: I guess you can Seq-seq in tensorflow. Please refer this link:
https://handong1587.github.io/deep_learning/2015/10/09/segmentation.html

Comment: Just put a softmax layer on the end of the LSTM layers. Ta-da! It's now a classifier.